# Assigning new value to object property

Tags: javascript, function, email, object

I need to figure out how to update the user with a new email. I've assigned a current email in the user object but need the function to change the object property of email. I've done what I know and can't seem to figure out what I need to put in the function to make this happen. Any suggestions would be so helpful!

```
var user = {email: "stefano@gmail.com"};

function changeEmail(user, newEmail) {

}

changeEmail(user, "paul@gmail.com");
```

The assignment instructions are: Create a function called changeEmail that takes in a user object and a newEmail string. 
Replace the user's current email address (assigned to the email property) with the newEmail string, then return the updated user object.

Comment: `user.email = userEmail; return user`

Comment: That didn't work. There is no userEmail object. Just kidding. I just saw the return user part of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing the reference of user to the function you can simply do

```js
var user = {email: "stefano@gmail.com"};

function changeEmail(user, newEmail) {
    user.email = newEmail;
}

changeEmail(user, "paul@gmail.com");

console.log(user);
```

which would change the value of user